# Writing strings after looping

Tags: java, string, list, loops

I am incorrectly looping through a list of FreeEvent Objects, which consist of a String and a corresponding Enum.

```
private List<FreeEvent> freeEvents = new ArrayList<FreeEvent>();
```

My JUnit test gives out the following error, which is self-explanatory:

*org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected: Halloween Evening[1: FREE Halloween Evening2: FREE Halloween Evening3: FREE ] but was:Halloween Evening[3: FREE]*

I understand what the error is, but I am not sure how to fix the loop to make it remember all the values it looped through.

```
public String displayFreeEvents() {

    String name = null;
    EventType type = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < freeEvents.size(); i++) {
        name = freeEvents.get(i).getEventName();
        type = freeEvents.get(i).getEventType();
    }

    String event = name + ": " + type;
    return event;

}
```

Test Case

```
     public void testDisplayFreeEvents() {
    EventHistory eventHistory = new EventHistory();

    FreeEvent event1 = new FreeEvent("Halloween Evening1",EventType.FREE);
    FreeEvent event2 = new FreeEvent("Halloween Evening2",EventType.FREE);
    FreeEvent event3 = new FreeEvent("Halloween Evening3",EventType.FREE);

    eventHistory.addFreeEvent(event1);
    eventHistory.addFreeEvent(event2);
    eventHistory.addFreeEvent(event3);

    assertEquals("Halloween Evening1: FREE"+"\n"+"Halloween Evening2: FREE"+"\n"+"Halloween Evening3: FREE"+"\n",eventHistory.displayFreeEvents());

 }
```

Comment: can you post your test case?

Comment: You're iterating but do not do anything with `name` and `type` until after the `for` loop, so they have the last values from `freeEvents.get(freeEvents.size()-1)`.

Comment: I also don't see line break happening, though in assert you expect it with ```\n```

Comment: It's usually better to use System.lineSeparator instead of "\n".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class in order to build your string through the iteration.

So , your method should look like this :

```
public String displayFreeEvents() {

  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < freeEvents.size(); i++) {
    String name = "", type = "";
    name = freeEvents.get(i).getEventName();
    type = freeEvents.get(i).getEventType();
    stringBuilder.append(name+ " " + type); // you can add also the \n character if you wish
  }


  return stringBuilder.toString();
```

}